# Problem using KarhunenLoeveDecomposition

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, series-expansion, code-request, coefficients

I have a matrix called stochasticData.mat which size is 211302*50 and I need to perform the [Karhunen-Loève decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem) on it to calculate the uncorrelated random variables. Note that stochasticData.mat has 50 realizations of a stochastic random process measured in 211302 points. I think that I can use the [KarhunenLoeveDecomposition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KarhunenLoeveDecomposition.html) function. However, I am not and advanced user, so I don't know what I am doing. I have attempted what can be seen in the following code:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
stochasticData = Import["stochasticData.mat"]
KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[{stochasticData}]
```

Unfortunately, as can be seen in the attached figure, my result seems wrong. Can someone please tell me what to do to find the independent random variables?
[image]

Comment: Remove the curly bracket around stochasticData.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, writing `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[stochasticData]` returns the same result